# Is there a way to access app-specific external storage folder with media store?

Tags: java, android, storage, mediastore, android-10.0

As the title says i'm saving some files - mostly audio - in my app specified External directory (android/data/com.xxx.xxx), now i want to access to those audio files with Mediastore but i can't how should i do this?
is it possible for media store to access this kind of private directory?

it worth mentioning that the whole data directory has a .nomedia file

UPDATE :

files are saved in .../android/data/com.xxx.xxx/files/music were `getExternalFilesDir` stores files

mediastore finds other audio files but it can't access to my files in that directory

```
context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                BASE_PROJECTION, selection, selectionValues, sortOrder);
```

UPDATE2: 
used following scan after creating files

```
private void copyAssets() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] files = null;
    try {
        files = assetManager.list("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
    }
    if (files != null) for (String filename : files) {
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            in = assetManager.open(filename);

            File outFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC), filename);
            out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            copyFile(in, out);

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
            // immediately available to the user.
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                    new String[] { outFile.toString() }, null,
                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                        }
                    });

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
        }
        finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // NOOP
                }
            }
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // NOOP
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Comment: `my app specified directory (android/data/com.xxx.xxx), ` ?? That is no valid path. Can you give full path please. Which Android version in use?

Comment: Further you did not tell how exactly you want to access the media store for your files. Please rephrase. Put all in your post.

Comment: my question isn't about implementing the code 
everything works as they should 
my question is , is it possible for media store to access this kind of private directory?

Comment: Every body can access those app specific directories. Well below Android Q one can. So the media store can too. Why not? And you are still mentioning an invalid path.

Comment: yes they do 
but even media scanner in music players don't scan thos directories i don't know maybe because of .nomedia file, but i even used a media scan after creating files still no change

Comment: I think that the mediascanner omits those directories yes. So they are not known by the mediastore. Everybody has access to those directories, even the mediastore, but they will not be scanned. Hence not in the database of the media store.

Comment: so what can i do ? doesn't the fact that the app is trying to access to it's own folder make any difference here? in case of using mediastore

Comment: Its own folder? But we do not know what you are doing as you did not show initialisation code for `BASE_PROJECTION, selection, selectionValues, sortOrder)`. We can only guess and we wont.

Comment: Further we do not know the values for `Uri uri` and `path. So we do not know what` you are doing for scan.

Comment: @blackapps i found the solution checkout the answer , thank you for answering tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK after searching and debugging for a day and half i found this solution:
Media Store doesn't have access to app specific external directory and in order to media store have access to them you should copy your files to a media directory as below :

```
private void copyFiles() {

    File directory = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).toString());
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
    {

        String videoFileName = files[i].getName();

        ContentValues valuesaudios;
        valuesaudios = new ContentValues();
        valuesaudios.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Music/" + "Folder");
        valuesaudios.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, videoFileName);
        valuesaudios.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, videoFileName);
        valuesaudios.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
        valuesaudios.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
        valuesaudios.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
        valuesaudios.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, 1);
        ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri collection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
        Uri uriSavedAudio = resolver.insert(collection, valuesaudios);


        ParcelFileDescriptor pfd;

        try {
            pfd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uriSavedAudio, "w");

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
            File storageDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).toString());
            File imageFile = new File(storageDir, files[i].getName());

            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(imageFile);


            byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {

                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }


            out.close();
            in.close();
            pfd.close();




        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        valuesaudios.clear();
        valuesaudios.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_PENDING, 0);
        getContentResolver().update(uriSavedAudio, valuesaudios, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(this, files[i].getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



}
```

Comment: `File storageDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).toString());
            File imageFile = new File(storageDir, files[i].getName());

            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(imageFile);`? Replace that by `FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(files[i]);`.

Comment: `... in order to media store have access to them you should copy your files...` That is a strange solution. You make copies. And then the media store knows the copies. But still the media store does not know the original files. I wonder why you first put them in such an app specific directory. Put them right where you want them. You can do it in copyAssets() directly.

Comment: yeah i will do that eventually. this just was a test i don't have files in my assets in real app, cause android10 doesn't allow writing anywhere you want anymore so i need to copy my files to make them visible to mediastore